# QR Code Detector?

Tags: ros, 2d-image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is anyone aware of a QR code detector library, preferrably in Python, that's efficient enough to locate and track QR Codes in an image in real-time? I'm trying to program a small robot to search for a specific QR code, and then once it's found, track its movement and follow it around.

I've found a ton of encoders, for generating QR Codes, and decoders, for reading the text from the pristine generated images, but there seems to almost nothing for detecting QR codes from raw noisy images or video feeds. Considering how many QR reading Android apps there are, I find this difficult to believe.

I've found a few proof-of-concept tutorials like [this](https://github.com/bharathp666/opencv_qr) and [this](http://blog.ayoungprogrammer.com/2014/04/real-time-qr-code-bar-code-detection.html/), but these look like hacky one-offs that are no longer maintained, or even packaged properly.

I've also found a couple ROS projects like [this](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_vision) and [this](http://wiki.ros.org/visp_auto_tracker), but these also look unmaintained, as well as enormously over-complicated, and need extensive calibration. Is there anything else I'm missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245744/qr-code-detector?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2016-10-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JoshMarino](https://answers.ros.org/users/27952/joshmarino/) on 2016-10-14**:
[ar_track_alvar](http://wiki.ros.org/ar_track_alvar) I have used before for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Vision visp is not just for reading but also tracking the qr codes: http://wiki.ros.org/visp_auto_tracker

For just reading you might want to look at http://wiki.ros.org/zbar_ros

Most people use AR tags though and http://wiki.ros.org/ar_track_alvar it's optimized for the tracking elements not data carrying like QR codes.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-11-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0